# Tugglebutton и заполнение listview

Tags: java, android, xml

Здравствуйте, помогите пожалуйста, имеется `tugglebutton` и `listview` заполняющийся из двух массивов, как сделать так чтобы при одном положении `taglebutton` в `listview` выводился первый массив, а при другом положении второй.

**код xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.orshagoes.number_1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:text="Направление:"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:layout_gravity="right"/>

        <ToggleButton
            android:id="@+id/toggleButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:checked="false"
            android:text="ToggleButton"
            android:textOff="ОБРАТНОЕ ↓"
            android:textOn="ПРЯМОЕ ↑" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**код активити:**

```
package com.example.admin.orshagoes;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class number_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    String [] arr; //={"Вокзал", "Школа №12"};
    ListView listView1;
    String [] arrob;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_1);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        arrob = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1ob);
        arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1);

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        // Создаём адаптер ArrayAdapter, чтобы привязать массив к ListView
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);

        // Привяжем массив через адаптер к ListView
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                finish();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Добавляем `List` элементов, через который будем менять отображение
- Вешаем обработчик на изменения состояний кнопки
  `setOnCheckedChangeListener`.
- Внутри его меняем данные адаптера
  `adapterList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrob));` \ `adapterList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));`
- Сообщаем View, что в адаптере новые данные и
  их нужно перерисовать `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

---

```
public void setMyAdapter(final ArrayAdapter adapter){
    ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
    toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            adapterList.clear();
            if (isChecked) {
                adapterList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrob));
            } else {
                adapterList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
            }
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    });
}
```

---

В вашем коде будет выглядеть так:

```
public class number_1 extends AppCompatActivity {

    String [] arr; //={"Вокзал", "Школа №12"};
    ListView listView1;
    String [] arrob;
    List<String> adapterList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_number_1);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);

        arrob = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1ob);
        arr = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names1);

        adapterList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(arr));

        listView1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview1);

        // Создаём адаптер ArrayAdapter, чтобы привязать массив к ListView
       ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, adapterList);

        // Привяжем массив через адаптер к ListView
        listView1.setAdapter(adapter);

        setMyAdapter(adapter);
    }

        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == android.R.id.home) {
                finish();
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        public void setMyAdapter(final ArrayAdapter adapter){
            ToggleButton toggle = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
            toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
                    adapterList.clear();
                    if (isChecked) {
                       adapterList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arrob));
                    } else {
                        adapterList.addAll(Arrays.asList(arr));
                    }
                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }
}
```

Comment: Не могли бы вы если не сложно вставить свою конструкцию в мой код, а то я вставляю ошибки вылетают.

Comment: @Mitar поправил

Comment: красным setmyadapoter выделяет

Comment: вы вставили метод `setMyAdapter` в класс `number_1`? Кстати классы в Java лучше называть с большой буквы и без нижних подчёркиваний

Comment: вроде так вставил не понимаю в чем дело

Comment: куда пихать эту строчку? `ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arr);`

Comment: Она стоит там где надо

Comment: Ошибка пропала, но тупо данные не выводит

Comment: Подождите несколько минут, сейчас создам проект.

Comment: вот, проверил, работает